# String Convert to JSON object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have this code:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

            var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonString = String.Empty;

            context.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
            {

                jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();

            }
     }
```

Up code get json string and write in jsonString.
jsonString result return

```
{"id":"54","name":"reza"}
```

How can i convert jsonString to JsonObject and parse it?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NewtonSoft json](http://james.newtonking.com/json) library for c# and use below code

Create a class to hold the result

```
Class Person 
{
public int id {get;set;} 
public string name {get;set;} 
}

var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonString);

if you dont want to create class use JObject 

dynamic newObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
string id= newObj.id ;
string name= newObj.name;
```

Comment: This works create with .net standard 1.0, and is probably the only serialization that works with this framework.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
Use Newtonsoft.Json (Get package from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)

```
using (var inputStream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
                {
                   var jsonString = inputStream.ReadToEnd();                       
                    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(jsonString);
                    return data;
                }
```

**Solution 2**
Please follow the following Post

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/79435/Deserialize-JSON-with-C